# PDOException Could not find driver in Console Command Symfony2

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, php-pgsql

I am trying to run a Console command. I created command which ran successfully, but when I tried to connect to database, it shows an error on Console:

> [PDOException] could not find driver

I am using this to get record from database

```
$conn = $this->getContainer()->get('database_connection');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = 1";
$data = $conn->fetchAssoc($sql);
$output->writeln($data['field_name']);
```

I am using PostgreSQL with Doctrine DBAL

I am using this command in Windows command line to run the Console command in Symfony:

```
> php app/console demo:actionfordb
```

Please guide me what and where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check your php.ini used by your php client (not the one used by apache or IIS) to be sure that pdo_pgsql extension is loaded

Comment: Yes, that's what was the issue. I had 2 versions of PHP stored in Environment variables. The one running was causing the issue. Thank you!